Transforming Java POJOs and nested streams(Java 8), with possibility of null inner stream
Say I have following java POJOs
class Outer {
  Config;
  List<Warning> warnings;

}

class Config {
  String configId;
  String configName;
}

class Warning {
  String warningId;
  String warningName;
}


class Transformed {
  String configId
  String configName;
  String warningId;
  String warningName;
}

Desired output
List<Transformed>
In an ideal world where for ever instance of Outer, if warnings were always present I could use Java 8 streams and transform into List<Transformed. But List<Warning> warnings can be null in some cases of input. One might say, use something like Stream.ofNullable when doing an inner stream. This will not work in my use case because I still want the Tranformed instance to have the fields String configId and String configName populated even if the warning fields are null. How do I do it with Java 8 streams, and filter combo? What is the ideal way? Or I just go the plain old fashioned nested looping way with null checks and all?

So, you have a stream of Outer and want a stream of Transformed? How do you expect nulls to be converted to field values?

The corresponding fields in Transformed for the warning can remain null.

Assuming proper constructors, you might want to use flatMap combined with a ternary operator: List<Transformed> output = input.stream().flatMap(outer -> outer.warnings == null ? Stream.of(new Transformed(outer.config.configId, outer.config.configName)) : outer.warnings.stream().map(warning -> new Transformed(outer.config.configId, outer.config.configName, warning.warningId, warning.warningName))).collect(Collectors.toList());
Although it would make sense to have two constructors in the Transformed class, one accepting a Config instance and one both Config and Warning as parameters

thanks @AlexisC. This is good and works. I got greedy now. Followup. How do I split my original outer stream based on .filter on it on warningss being null and then applying different map operation to the 2 split streams and then joining them? That might be another way. Just not able to code it :( Sorry

Can warnings also be an empty list, and do you want the same output in that case? (I recommend representing “no warnings” by an empty list rather than null.)

@Anonymous, empty list will do as well. My main struggle is how to just do it via streams with as minimal of if else null check. You have an example snippet?

To handle an empty warning list the same way, in the code by @AlexisC.just replace outer.warnings == null with (outer.warnings == null || outer.warnings.isEmpty()).

How about this? You can always get the list of Transformed even if the warnings are null.
Stream.of(outer).flatMap(out -> {
                if (out.getWarnings() == null)
                    return Stream.of(new Transformed(out.getConfig().getConfigId(),
                            out.getConfig().getConfigName(), null, null));
                else {
                    return out.getWarnings().stream().map(w -> new Transformed(out.getConfig().getConfigId(),
                            out.getConfig().getConfigName(), w.getWarningId(), w.getWarningName()));

                }
            })
            .collect(toList());

